# Drupal: new content module for manage lists

Tags: drupal, list, module

Does anybody known about module for new content type "Lists", like a module WebForms used for manage different web forms, it ("Lists") manage different lists.

For example,

Admin create content of "Lists" (something like this.../node/add/list), where set up as minimum:

- name, title and other common things;
- fields of every record in list (like fields in WebForms);
- setup hierarchy (how many level deep).

User can manage created list (.../node/???):

- add/delete folders (for hierarchy);
- add/delete records in folders (or root) fills all fields;
- move records betweens folders;
- browse list.

P.S. I try to search on drupal.org but word "list" is very "garbage" and I cannot find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout NodeQueue module. This is closest to your description http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue

Comment: Thanks, but if for "collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list", but I need "ordered list in every node" or "list (of some elements) as a node".

Comment: You may look into NodeReference module. This module adds a list field in your Node or Content Type and allows you to select other nodes in a list. This module is part of CCK.